# Find pattern in a string, then place characters after string in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a variable **(OUTPUT)** which contains

```
"Using pin #4 Data (40): 0x23 0x0 0x18 0x0 0x3b Temp = 24 *C, Hum = 35 %".
```

Both the **Temp** and **Hum** can be 0 to 100.

In **BASH** how do I find the `string "Temp = " and "Hum = "` then place the related numbers("24" and "35") in their respective variables TEMP and HUM.

The length of the OUTPUT variable can change, so I can't find the TEMP and HUM variables based on their position in the string.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ OUTPUT="Using pin #4 Data (40): 0x23 0x0 0x18 0x0 0x3b Temp = 24 *C, Hum = 35 %"
$ [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ Temp\ =\ ([0-9]*) ]] && TEMP=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ Hum\ =\ ([0-9]*) ]] && HUM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
$ echo $TEMP 
24
$ echo $HUM
35
```

Comment: Works like a charm, first time I have seen that "BASH_REMATCH", not too much about it on the internet. Thank-you very much

Answer (score 0):

Neat alternate solution :

```
grep -oE " [0-9]+ " <<< $OUTPUT
```